# Parse and clean large log files

Tags: performance, bash, awk

I have the code below, which works successfully, and is used to parse, clean log files (very large in size) and output into smaller sized files. Output filename is the first 2 characters of each line. However, if there is a special character in these 2 characters, then it needs to be replaced with a '_'. This will help ensure there is no illegal character in the filename.

This would take about 12-14 mins to process 1 GB worth of logs (on my laptop). Can this be made faster?

For example, would it help to run this parallel? I am aware I could do `}' "$FILE" &`. However, I tested and that does not help much. Perhaps AWK itself could run in parallel (the equivalent of  `print $0 >> Fpath &` )?

**Sample log file**

```
email1@foo.com:datahere2     
email2@foo.com:datahere2
email3@foo.com datahere2
email5@foo.com;dtat'ah'ere2 
wrongemailfoo.com
nonascii@row.com;data.is.junk-Œœ
email3@foo.com:datahere2
```

**Expected Output**

```
# cat em 
email1@foo.com:datahere2     
email2@foo.com:datahere2
email3@foo.com:datahere2
email5@foo.com:dtat'ah'ere2 
email3@foo.com:datahere2

# cat errorfile
wrongemailfoo.com
nonascii@row.com;data.is.junk-Œœ
```

**Code:**

```
#/bin/sh
pushd "_test2" > /dev/null
for FILE in *
do
    awk '
    BEGIN {
        FS=":"
    }
    {
        gsub(/^[ \t"'\'']+|[ \t"'\'']+$/, "")
        $0=gensub("[,|;: \t]+",":",1,$0)
        if (NF>1 && $1 ~ /^[[:alnum:]_.+-]+@[[:alnum:]_.-]+\.[[:alnum:]]+$/ && $0 ~ /^[\x00-\x7F]*$/)
        {
            Fpath=tolower(substr($1,1,2))
            Fpath=gensub("[^[:alnum:]]","_","g",Fpath)
            print $0 >> Fpath
        }
        else
            print $0 >> "errorfile"
    }' "$FILE"
done
popd > /dev/null
```

Comment: To the reviewers: I think this question has been edited into shape good enough that it's within the scope of the site. Please leave a comment if you disagree.

Comment: Mast: i disagree. your edits wont make the code run any faster. in future pls post your answer separately, and not edit the original ques

Comment: @rogerwhite You may find this blog post helpful: http://aosabook.org/en/posa/working-with-big-data-in-bioinformatics.html ..

Comment: @akki - sorry for the slow revert. all good, but i need help with the code !!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps switching the outputfile for each line can be avoided by sorting the inputfiles first or with some changes in your script:

```
# Store the 2-letter filenames
outfile[Fpath];
# Store the highest index for given outputfile
i[Fpath]++;
# Store current line in output array for that file
a[Fpath][i[Fpath]]=$0
# And in the END block print for array per output file
      for (out in outfile) {
         for (j=1;j<=i[out]; j++) {
            print a[out][j] >> out;
         }
      }
```

This results in

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        FS=":"
    }
    {
        gsub(/^[ \t"'\'']+|[ \t"'\'']+$/, "")
        $0=gensub("[,|;: \t]+",":",1,$0)
        if (NF>1 && $1 ~ /^[[:alnum:]_.+-]+@[[:alnum:]_.-]+\.[[:alnum:]]+$/ && $0 ~ /^[\x00-\x7F]*$/)
        {
            Fpath=tolower(substr($1,1,2))
            Fpath=gensub("[^[:alnum:]]","_","g",Fpath);
            outfile[Fpath];
            i[Fpath]++;
            a[Fpath][i[Fpath]]=$0
        }
        else
            print $0 >> "errorfile"
    }
   END {
      for (out in outfile) {
         for (j=1;j<=i[out]; j++) {
            print a[out][j] >> out;
         }
      }
   } ' "$FILE"
```